# How to generate Rails form dynamically dependant on languages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, fields-for

I have a form and I want to show some form elements x times dependent on languages in Langs table, it is nested attributes with has_many association. I am trying to use `fields_for` but with no success.

I have a Lang objects and this code in template.

```
  <%= fields_for :categories_versions, @langs do |lang| %>
    <div class="card mt-4 mb-4">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="container mt-4">
          <%= "Category for #{Lang.find(lang.id).lang}" %><br/>
```

it yields ActionView object, but I want to access every `lang` in `@langs` (which is simply `Lang.all`.

And it generates me just one set, but I have 2 languages, so my desired output is form with 2 sets of columns for every of two languages with name of the language.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object that is given to you by `fields_for` (namely the `|lang|` in your example) is a form helper, not an object from the `@lang` collection. So to get the id of current `lang` you would need to do `lang.object.id`. I'd suggest you change `|lang|` to `|lang_f|` to avoid confusion. Also if `@langs` is not of the same type as `:categories_versions`, I am not sure this is going to work properly. You probably want something like:

```
<% @langs.each do |lang| %>
  <%= fields_for :categories_versions do |version_f| %>    
    <%= "Category for #{lang.name}" %><br/>

    <%# You will probably want to associate the category version with the lang. %>
    <%# Maybe like this. Depends on how you set it up %>
    <%= version_f.hidden_field :lang_id, lang.id %>
    ...
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I am making some assumptions here, so adjust to your actual attributes and models.

Comment: Thanks this can help perfectly, but as you said, it has other issues. I stopped trying to store such a structure (including validations etc) and created separate forms, just for keep things easy. Thank you!